# How to Re-Enable VS Code Errors

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I'm experiencing a strange phenomenon in which errors (I believe compile errors) are no longer being picked up by the VS Code SFDX code. Normally when I run "SFDX: Deploy this source to org", it checks for errors and the deployment fails if any are found. But sometime today that stopped.

As an example, I ran `confsdfsole.log("test");` instead of `console.log("test");`, and it deployed without issue.

Does anyone know how to turn error checking back on?

**Edit: Things I have tried**

- Re-running `npm install`
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the Salesforce Extension Pack

Comment: I tested versions of sfdx-cli up to about a month ago, none of them complain about this problem. Maybe you had a plugin that was checking for additional problems? I would try `npm install` in your project folder to make sure all of the relevant plugins are installed.

Comment: @sfdcfox just gave that a try, unfortunately it did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to determine the issue. For some reason the ESLint feature of the Salesforce Extension Pack was disabled. I noticed in the bottom-right corner of the screen the ESLINT icon in red with a cross-out circle next to it (image 1 below). I clicked on it and received a pop-up window that gave me the option to allow ESLint for the project (image 2 below). I clicked "Allow Everywhere" and the error catching was restored.

[image]

[image]